# Animating Textfield Of Cell Using FRC

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation

I have a table view that uses an FRC. Whenever the table view is updated by the FRC, I would like the following behavior...

**Insert Cell**

The cell shows up like normal. However, the text does not all appear at once. It shows up one character at a time with a ~0.1 second delay between characters.

**Edit Cell**

The text does not change from old -> new right away, but rather one character at a time (again, a ~0.1 second delay between each character change).

---

I have already written an algorithm that can handle making the minimum changes to the text field. However, I have no idea how to implement any of this into the table view & FRC.
Any ideas?

Comment: How about putting your algorithm in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` when you set text?

Comment: This is what I'm working on now. But how do I filter it so it only gets called when the FRC calls cellForRow?

Comment: You can set a boolean flag when you add cell or edit, turn it off when it's done. Also FRC has delegate method `controllerWillChangeContent` or `didChangeObject`, maybe you can set your flag there.